# Issues with Inline-Block making Images Smaller?

Tags: php, wordpress, row, css

I'm trying to get these three images on this page to load in one after each other. When I set it to "Inline-Block" in css, it works, but the images get really small.

https://www.palmersdeliandmarket.com/holiday/

Here's my CSS:

```
.categories ul li a.current { font-weight: bold; }
#shopp .category { position: relative; display: inline-block;}
#shopp .views { display: inline; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; }
#shopp .views button { border: 1px solid transparent; background: none; cursor: pointer;          padding: 2px; margin-bottom: -3px; }
#shopp .views button.hover { background-color: #ebebeb; border: 1px solid #777; }
#shopp .views li { display: inline; }
#shopp .orderby { float: right; }
```

and my HTML:

```
<?php if(shopp('category','hasproducts','load=coverimages')): ?>
<div class="alignright"><?php shopp('category','pagination','show=10'); ?></div>
<ul class="products">
    <li class="row"><ul>
    <?php while(shopp('category','products')): ?>
    <?php if(shopp('category','row')): ?></ul></li><li class="row"><ul><?php endif; ?>
        <li class="product">
            <div class="frame">
            <a href="<?php shopp('product','url'); ?>"><?php shopp('product','coverimage','setting=gallery-previews'); ?></a>
                <div class="details">
                <h4 class="name"><a href="<?php shopp('product','url'); ?>"><?php shopp('product','name'); ?></a></h4>
                <p class="price"><?php shopp('product','saleprice','starting=from'); ?> </p>
                <?php if (shopp('product','has-savings')): ?>
                    <p class="savings">Save <?php shopp('product','savings','show=percent'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="listview">
                    <p><?php shopp('product','summary'); ?></p>
                    <form action="<?php shopp('cart','url'); ?>" method="post" class="shopp product">
                    <?php shopp('product','addtocart'); ?>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="alignright"><?php shopp('category','pagination','show=10'); ?></div>

</div>
    <?php else: ?>
  <?php if (!shopp('catalog','is-landing')): ?>
  <?php shopp('catalog','breadcrumb'); ?>
  <h3><?php shopp('category','name'); ?></h3>
  <p>No products were found.</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't see any inline-block in your CSS.

Comment: There's problem with your HTML. The first and the rest images are located in different <div class="category"></div> tags, thus they cannot be aligned on the same line easily.

Why do you think it creates different category divs? Maybe because it tries to sort products for you in HTML?

Comment: @Fratyr Yeah, the first image is in a different category than the other two images so it just defaults to start a new row.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex I added the inline-block for your reference, I just didn't want the issue to be live while working on it.

Comment: @Fratyr I'm also using the Shopp plugin, and on the backend of Wordpress, I call them in using:  
    '[catalog-collection slug="holiday-gift-cards"][catalog-collection slug="holiday-platters"]'

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` + `width: auto` gives a width only large enough to fit the contents. Add `width: 100%`.